# Rails 3.2 integration testing a login system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have followed the RailsCasts episode to do authentication from scratch: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised

Now I would like to do integration testing using the built-in test framework.

In my database I have fields for email and password_digest (among others), as I'm using has_secure_password.  In my fixture for Users I have

```
account_administrator:
  email: account_administrator@test.com
  password_digest: password
  first_name: Bob
  last_name: Jones
  is_team_member: true
  is_direct_manager: false
  is_senior_leadership: false
  is_reviewer: false
  is_account_administrator: true
```

In my integration test I have

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserFlowsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  fixtures :users

  def login(user)
    open_session do |s|
      u = users(user)
      s.https!
      s.post "/sessions", email: u.email, password: "password"
      assert_redirected_to root_url
    end
  end



  test "logging in" do
    login(:account_administrator)
  end

end
```

The problem I'm having is that the "logging in" test fails with this error:

```
  1) Error:
test_logging_in(UserFlowsTest):
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash: invalid hash
```

I think it is because the "hash" I provided in my fixture is not a real password_digest--it's just the string "password".  How can I fix this to make my test work?

Answer (score 0):

Create the user manually with password='password' in the database, from the app UI, or from rails console (`User.create(...)`). Then use the rails console to find the password_digest (`User.first.password_digest`) - then paste that password_digest into the password_digest field in the fixture and it should work.

Comment: Would this be a security concern to have the email, password, and password digest all together in the clear?  Especially if it is committed to a public code repository?